# Java error: cannot find symbol, and can't figure out why

Tags: java

**Error:**

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

**What appears doesn't works:**

If I write: "InvoerVakhandler extends boven" then the error disapears but then I get an endless loop and in the end the program crashes and says stack overflow error.

If I try to change the "}" symbol from class boven and place it in the end of the text then I even get more error messages.

**Question:** What do I have to change in my code to make it work?

**Note:**
I'm new to Java and I know there are more posts like this one but I just can't apply them to my code with my current limited understanding of Java.

If someone wants to know: I'm using JCreator.

**What i'm trying to make:** What I'm trying to make is fairly simple.

1) Fill in a name in the JTextField, press enter and the name should appear in the JTextArea. After the name is in the JTextArea the JTextField becomes empty so you can fill another name and so on there should appear a list of names in JTextArea. (this is what I'm now trying to make)

2) Push the button kiesWin to make the program choose a random person from the list.

3) Push the button resetL to reset the program so I can make a new list to choose a random winner from it.

**Part of the code where the error appears:** (from the class InvoerVakHandler)

```
String invoer = invoervak1.getText();
```

With my limited knowledge of java the problem could be litterly anywhere so in case I will post the whole code.

**Whole code:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

// Main method to make the frame
public class Loterij3 extends JFrame {
public static void main( String args[] ) {
    JFrame frame = new Loterij3();
    frame.setExtendedState( frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setTitle( "Klanten Register" );
    frame.setContentPane( new Paneel() );
    frame.setVisible( true );
}
}

class Paneel extends JPanel {
private boven Boven;
JTextArea textvak1;
JTextField textvak2;
OnthoudNaam onthoudNaam = new OnthoudNaam();

public Paneel() {
setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); // using border Layout.
setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );

textvak1 = new JTextArea();
add( new JScrollPane( textvak1 ) );
textvak1.setBackground( Color.WHITE );

textvak2 = new JTextField();
textvak2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
textvak2.setEditable( false );

Boven = new boven();    

add( Boven, BorderLayout.NORTH );
add( textvak1, BorderLayout.CENTER );
add( textvak2, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
}

public class boven extends Paneel {
JButton kiesWin, resetL;
JLabel label1;
JTextField invoervak1;

public boven() {
    setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
    setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, 4, 100, 5 ) ); // using GridLayout.
    Border border = 
        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder( 10, 10, 10, 10 );
    setBorder( border );

    kiesWin = new JButton("Kies een Winnaar!");
    kiesWin.addActionListener( new kies() );
    resetL = new JButton("Reset alles");
    resetL.addActionListener( new reset() );
    label1 = new JLabel("Voer Persoon in en druk op enter: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
    invoervak1 = new JTextField( 20 );
    invoervak1.addActionListener( new InvoerVakHandler() );

    add( label1 );
    add( invoervak1 );
    add( kiesWin );
    add( resetL );
    }
}

// de naam
class naam {
    private String ingevoerdNaam;

    public naam( String ingevoerdNaam) {
        this.ingevoerdNaam = ingevoerdNaam;
    }

    public String getIngevoerdNaam() {
        return ingevoerdNaam;
    }
}

// Arraylist
class OnthoudNaam extends JPanel {
    private ArrayList<naam> lijst;

    public OnthoudNaam() {
        lijst = new ArrayList<naam>();
        }

        public void voegNaamToe(naam x ) {
        lijst.add(x);
        }

        public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(naam x : lijst ) {
        buffer.append( x );
        buffer.append( "\n" );
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
}

// this is the part where the code goes wrong
public class InvoerVakHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        String invoer = invoervak1.getText();
        naam naam = new naam( invoer );
        onthoudNaam.voegNaamToe( naam );
        textvak1.setText( onthoudNaam.toString() );
    }
}
    // kies
class kies implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    }
}

// reset
class reset implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    }
}
}
```

**For everyone who is trying to help me: Thank you for all your help and patience in advance!**

Comment: You should have `}` before `public class boven extends Paneel {`

Comment: Could you provide which line specifically is causing this error?  In general, these errors occur when you're using a variable you haven't defined within the scope of where it's being requested.

Comment: @MarounMaroun:  I can see that there's the appropriate number of curly braces...

Comment: @Makoto I missed one, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in question in in class: `InvoerVakHandler`

The variable is defined in class: `boven`

That is why it can't find it.

I think you can get the source of the event from the `ActionEvent` passed to the `actionPerformed()` method.

Note that normally we use an upper-case letter to begin the name of any class and lower case to begin methods and variables. (Constants are an exception.)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `invoervak1` is defined in the `boven` class and is not visible within `InvoerVakHandler`. Since `InvoerVakHandler` is registered exclusively with the `invoervak1` component, you can use the source object of your `ActionListener` to obtain the reference to the `JTextField`:

```
JTextField textField = (JTextField) e.getSource();
String invoer = textField.getText();
```

Typically anonymous `ActionListener` implementations are used. This makes the intended source clear along with its associated functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The error goes away with the answers from Reimeus. However your program will not run because you created a stackoverflow.
In the class Paneel you call

```
Boven = new boven();
```

However boven extends from your Paneel class. So Java needs to build a Paneel instance when building a Boven instance which will require a Paneel and so on.

Make boven extend from JPanel and your GUI starts and works.

However your output will look like this

```
Paneel$naam@3dee7a6c
```

This happens because your class "naam" did not overwritte the toString method and so Object.toString is called which produces a String based on the class name and hashCode of a Object.

So extend your naam class to this:

```
    class naam {
    private String ingevoerdNaam;

    public naam( String ingevoerdNaam) {
        this.ingevoerdNaam = ingevoerdNaam;
    }

    public String getIngevoerdNaam() {
        return ingevoerdNaam;
    }

    public String toString() {
       return ingevoerdNaam;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. And like mentioned already please stick to the [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).