# Java Getting strange text as output from my program

Tags: java, awt

**Errors:**
When compiling there are no errors, when executing there are no errors and the program starts just as I wanted. BUT!

**Problem:**
What I want to achieve is simple. the text I fill in the JTextField should be put in the JTextArea.

**Example:** I type the word "Cat" in the JTextField, the arraylist remembers the word "Cat" and then the word Cat appears in the JTextArea. Then I repeat the process to create a big list of names. ( ofc I don't actually type the "" marks)

**Current output:** I type the word "Cat" and (I think) the arraylist remembers it and gives me the output: Paneel$naam@174aa60

**What I think this is:**
I am verry new to Java (I'm even new to programming) so I might be totaly wrong. Paneel$naam@174aa60: Paneel$naam tells me where it comes from and then i get the @ symbol (no clue what this symbol means in java) and then (I think) this is the hashcode of the word "Cat" 174 = C, aa = a and 60 = t. I read on multiple sites and I think this has something to do with class Object and something with toString.

**Question**
What do I have to change or add to my code to make it work properly? (did research and tried but with my limited knoledge i failed to succed)

**The whole code:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

// Main method to make the frame
public class Loterij3 extends JFrame {
public static void main( String args[] ) {
    JFrame frame = new Loterij3();
    frame.setExtendedState( frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setTitle( "Klanten Register" );
    frame.setContentPane( new Paneel() );
    frame.setVisible( true );
}
}

class Paneel extends JPanel {
private boven boven;
JTextArea textvak1;
JTextField textvak2;
OnthoudNaam onthoudNaam = new OnthoudNaam();
JTextField invoervak1;

public Paneel() {
setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); // using border Layout.
setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );

boven = new boven(); 

textvak1 = new JTextArea();
add( new JScrollPane( textvak1 ) );
textvak1.setBackground( Color.WHITE );

textvak2 = new JTextField();
textvak2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
textvak2.setEditable( false );  

add( boven, BorderLayout.NORTH );
add( textvak1, BorderLayout.CENTER );
add( textvak2, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
}


public class boven extends JPanel {
JButton kiesWin, resetL;
JLabel label1;

public boven() {
    setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
    setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, 4, 100, 5 ) ); // using GridLayout.
    Border border = 
        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder( 10, 10, 10, 10 );
    setBorder( border );

    kiesWin = new JButton("Kies een Winnaar!");
    kiesWin.addActionListener( new kies() );
    resetL = new JButton("Reset alles");
    resetL.addActionListener( new reset() );
    label1 = new JLabel("Voer Persoon in en druk op enter: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
    invoervak1 = new JTextField( 20 );
    invoervak1.addActionListener( new InvoerVakHandler() );

    add( label1 );
    add( invoervak1 );
    add( kiesWin );
    add( resetL );
    }
}

// de naam
class naam {
    private String ingevoerdNaam;

    public naam( String ingevoerdNaam) {
        this.ingevoerdNaam = ingevoerdNaam;
    }

    public String getIngevoerdNaam() {
        return ingevoerdNaam;
    }
}

// Arraylist
class OnthoudNaam extends JPanel {
    private ArrayList<naam> lijst;

    public OnthoudNaam() {
        lijst = new ArrayList<naam>();
        }

        public void voegNaamToe(naam x ) {
        lijst.add(x);
        }

        public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(naam x : lijst ) {
        buffer.append( x );
        buffer.append( "\n" );
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
}

// invoer handler
public class InvoerVakHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        String invoer = invoervak1.getText();
        naam naam = new naam( invoer );
        onthoudNaam.voegNaamToe( naam );
        textvak1.setText( onthoudNaam.toString() );
    }
}
    // kies
class kies implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    }
}

// reset
class reset implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    }

}
}
```

Comment: you'd probably be well served by a debugger of some sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite, it's just [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) being called on an instance of `naam`:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

So it's not the hash code of `Cat` - it's the hash code of your object.

To fix this, just override `toString`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ingevoerdNaam;
}
```

(As per your earlier question, I'd *still* recommend avoiding all these inner classes though, and I'd *still* recommend that you start following Java naming conventions.)

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447597/java-error-cannot-find-symbol-and-cant-figure-out-why/16448020#16448020):

However your output will look like this

```
Paneel$naam@3dee7a6c
```

This happens because your class "naam" did not overwritte the toString method and so Object.toString is called which produces a String based on the class name and hashCode of a Object.

So extend your naam class to this:

```
class naam {
private String ingevoerdNaam;

public naam( String ingevoerdNaam) {
    this.ingevoerdNaam = ingevoerdNaam;
}

public String getIngevoerdNaam() {
    return ingevoerdNaam;
}

public String toString() {
   return ingevoerdNaam;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your output comes from calling onthoudnaam.toString -- the output with the "@" symbol in it is typical of a toString method on an object that has no other toString written for it.  You can override toString in your Onthoudnaam class to return the text you want.

Answer (score 0):

Within method `OnthoudNaam`

```
buffer.append( x );
```

should be changed to:

```
buffer.append( x.getIngevoerdNaam() );
```

The reason for this bizarre output is that when you appending the object of `naam` (`x`) in StringBuffer `buffer` it is calling `toString()` method of `Object`. Which returns the `String` in this way:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

That's why you are getting such type of output like `Paneel$naam@174aa60`. You want to append the `ingevoerdNaam` value in `JTextArea` so , you should call `getIngevoerdNaam` method with the Object `x` of `naam`.